# How large of session data should I store in session files by using Laravel5.1

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have create an financial system I and manager very are concerned to store large of session data around 100KB to 400KB in session files by using **Laravel5.1** and we don't understand it is good or not because we not yet sure how large of session should be stored in session files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good approach for sessions with big data. You can also use database as alternative:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: Should you tell me the maximum of data size?
Because we just concern because we don't know any case will happen in the furture or not

Comment: Which one is  the best though if I store session data in a file in Larave without with database?

Comment: I don't think there is any limit when you're using session files. If I were you, I'd use session files in a case when you don't have tens of thousands users.

Comment: Can't help you with performance, I think you should just test both approaches and you'll see which one is faster.